# How would one approach authentication with traefik?

Tags: traefik

**Authenticating Requests Through Traefik**

I am looking at using traefik as a proxy for a set a microservices.

However I realised that traefik does not support a authentication mechanism such as the one provided by Kong.

I would like to register consumers with traefik and allow access based on authentication.

Is there a recommend approach to doing this?

Ideally I would like to forward all incoming requests to a service that authenticates the incoming request. However I can not find any way to do this with traefik by using a custom middleware.

In short, is there a way to add such a middleware to traefik and have it execute a remote check before allowing a request to pass though?

(The basic auth built in to traefik is very limited.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Traefik supports this currently. Are you using a service discovery layer behind Traefik like [Consul](https://www.consul.io/)/[Kubernetes Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-controllers)? If so, these services may support [ACL access](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/acl.html) to services.